# Returning Pojo WebService JaxWS. Renaming <return> node

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, pojo

I think it should be quite easy but I really can't make it work.

I'm returning a Pojo, from a WebMethod:

```java
@WebMethod
public SubCategoria getSubCategorias() throws JAXBException {

    SubCategoria a = subCategoriaEJB.getAllSubCategorias().get(1);

    return a;
}
```

I'm just returning the first one, to try.

Im using soapUI to test my Ws.

The response is:

```xml
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <S:Body>
          <ns2:getSubCategoriasResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webService/">
             <return>
                <categoria>
                   <descripcion>Categoria Unica</descripcion>
                   <idCategoria>1</idCategoria>
                </categoria>
                <descripcion>asd123213</descripcion>
                <idSubCategoria>2</idSubCategoria>
             </return>
          </ns2:getSubCategoriasResponse>
       </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

I want that "return" node to be called "SubCategoria". I can't really make it work with the XmlRootElement Annotation.

Here my Pojo (SubCategoria)

```java
    package ejb.Entidades;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


    @Entity
    @XmlRootElement(name="SubCategoria")
    public class SubCategoria {

        @Id
        private Integer idSubCategoria;

        @ManyToOne 
        private Categoria categoria;


        private String descripcion;


        public Integer getIdSubCategoria() {
            return idSubCategoria;
        }
        public void setIdSubCategoria(Integer idSubCategoria) {
            this.idSubCategoria = idSubCategoria;
        }

        public String getDescripcion() {
            return descripcion;
        }
        public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
        }
        public Categoria getCategoria() {
            return categoria;
        }
        public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
            this.categoria = categoria;
        }

    }
```

Someone with a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@WebResult` annotation:

```java
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "subCategoria")
public SubCategoria getSubCategorias() throws JAXBException {

    SubCategoria a = subCategoriaEJB.getAllSubCategorias().get(1);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Tibtof, thx. Sorry for answering so late. I was traveling and stopped working in this project. Cheers.